# How can I get back the old split screen behavior from Mojave in Catalina?

Tags: terminal, fullscreen, split-view

Back in macOS 10.14 Mojave, clicking down and then dragging on the zoom button would allow you to drag the window to one half of the display, and the window would become full-screen on that half, allowing you to then choose another window for the other side (similar to Windows 10).

[image: Split Screen macOS]

Unfortunately, that's been replaced with a rather clunky and unintuitive drop down menu which you have to stop on top of the button, wait for it, and then choose an option. I know this is for sidecar to work, but I don't have a Mac or iPad with sidecar capabilities and I value my gesture-based UI more than capabilities for an option I can't use. (Even if one does have it, why not just "drag up" instead of to a side or something, to send to SideCar?)

[image: Badly designed popup menu]

I'm wondering if there is a Terminal command or something which I can do to revert this to its old behavior. It would be one thing if you could still drag, but get this menu by pausing over it... but they just seemingly disabled (or ripped out entirely) this functionality in favor of a far worse one. I don't usually get bothered by little waits for animations or something, but this does feel like I'm stopping for a sizable amount of time, even for someone who values animations (probably because there is a literal pause in this process).

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better solution to enable the old functionality through the OS, but I would be surprised if so. But I've found the free, [open-source](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst) application [Amethyst](https://ianyh.com/amethyst/) has been great for my usage.

To make sure you're getting the exact functionality you want, I suggest going into Amethyst's Mouse Preferences and ensuring "resize windows using mouse" is enabled.
[image: Amethyst preferences]

Comment: So far I don't see anything that lets me do this: https://youtu.be/cYGrlEtqaVw

Comment: @SYGMAH You're correct; it doesn't support true fullscreen mode. That said, I highly doubt you'll find exactly what you're looking for, as when Apple issues updates, it's very rare that you can enable a specific functionality in a previous version. I do wish you the best in finding a solution, and sorry I couldn't give you a better answer.

Comment: I suppose considering that, Rectangle is probably as close as you can get. It gives you Aero snap like behavior, albeit not fullscreen more.